# MVC 3 Razor Ajax HttpDelete IIS6

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6, http-delete

I'm trying to execute a delete request via jQuery to a controller. Locally it works but when deployed to the server I receive a 501 status.

I have confirmed that for .cshtml that all verbs are accepted and that file verification is not needed (I read this elsewhere but I don't see what it would achieve anyway as I am not calling a cshtml page). Is there some other application extension I need to change allowances for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have confirmed that for .cshtml that all verbs are accepted and that file verification is not needed

Except that in ASP.NET MVC you are not sending requests to `.cshtml` files. In ASP.NET MVC you are sending requests to controller actions. And they depend on your routing configuration. Out of the box IIS 6.0 doesn't support extensionless urls, so you cannot use the default routes unless you [configure IIS](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/22/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx).

So you will have to allow the DELETE verb to whatever extension you are using in IIS 6.0, or if you have configured extensionless urls, you will need to enable it for the aspnet_isapi extension.

Comment: I don't think that's strictly true, I'm running ASP .NET 4 and I have extension-less urls working out of the box (see http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/22/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx). I have also added delete as an allowed verb for .axd extension.